# Odoo connect to outlook calendar timeout issue

Tags: outlook, calendar, odoo

I tried connecting to my Outlook calendar using the Calendar module provided by Odoo.

I synced my data successfully I can see all of the events.

But I'm getting an issue, when I'm on the calendar view:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='graph.microsoft.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)
```

I see this is connected to the timeout limit. I'm not sure where i am supposed to configure the timeout limit.

I tried adding the parameter cpu_time_limit in the odoo.conf file but that didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout of the request of Microsoft Graph is [hard coded in the code to 20](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/microsoft_account/models/microsoft_service.py#L15).
and it's passed to [`_do_request`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/microsoft_account/models/microsoft_service.py#L15) method so you can change it from the module itself and upgrade it.